# Glassfish4 Including external resources via virtual host

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, glassfish

I develop a upload function for my web app. Because applications are deployed via war I had to save uploaded files in an external directory. Now, I want to include that directory, so my html pages can reference to uploaded images. I read about the possability to create a virtual host, but It has not been function yet.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is creating glassfish-web.xml in webapp/WEB-INF with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/upload/* dir=C:/opt/oracle/webapps/asd"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```